# RabbitMQ message conversion issue

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am facing issue while converting message into Object format after consuming message at consumer end. I couldn't able to convert back to Student object. FYI, at producer end am using spring RabbitTemplate and at consumer end plain java api(Note#: I cannot use spring at consumer end)

**Issue:**
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.steelwedge.util.Student] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(StdValueInstantiator.java:379)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromString(StdValueInstantiator.java:268)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializer.java:765)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:585)

Producer Code: (using Spring-RabbitTemplate)

```
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setCompany("RLR");
    student.setName("Pandi");

    String jsonString =  new ObjectMapper().unMarshall(student);
    template.convertAndSend(jsonString);
```

Consumer Code:

```
String message = null;
             delivery = consumer.nextDelivery(100);
     if (delivery != null) {
        message = new String(delivery.getBody());
     }

             ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
         Student apiRequest = mapper.readValue(message, Student.class);
```

Comment: After so many trials I have a solution where we can send message by converting string into byte format at producer end on channel created from template.Channel channel = template.getConnectionFactory().createConnection().createChannel(false); channel.basicPublish("", queueName, null, jsonString .getBytes()); Do we have any solution instead doing this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what your `unMarshall()` method is, but I just tested with Jackson2 with no problems...

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setFoo("foo");
foo.setBar("bar");
String fooString = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(foo);
template.convertAndSend("", "foo", fooString);

Channel channel = cf.createConnection().createChannel(false);
GetResponse response = channel.basicGet("foo", true);
String in = new String(response.getBody());
Foo fooIn = new ObjectMapper().readValue(in, Foo.class);
System.out.println(fooIn);
```

However, you simplify the sending side and the framework will take care of the conversion...

```
template.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
template.convertAndSend("", "foo", foo);

response = channel.basicGet("foo", true);
in = new String(response.getBody());
fooIn = new ObjectMapper().readValue(in, Foo.class);
System.out.println(fooIn);
```

**EDIT:**

Just tested with Jackson 1 (codehaus) with no problems...

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setFoo("foo");
foo.setBar("bar");
String fooString = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(foo);
template.convertAndSend("", "foo", fooString);

Channel channel = cf.createConnection().createChannel(false);
GetResponse response = channel.basicGet("foo", true);
String in = new String(response.getBody());
Foo fooIn = new ObjectMapper().readValue(in, Foo.class);
System.out.println(fooIn);
```

Comment: I will try with Jackson 2 api, thank you for the detailed sample.